# Como debugar na Code::Blocks utilizando o compilador VS 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilação, ide, debug

Eu estou utilizando o `Visual Studio 2010 Express`. O problema é que a Syntax Highlighting é muito fraca e o `intellisense` (recurso que mostra os atributos dos objetos em quanto "você" digita) também deixa a desejar (não sei se é só na versão express).

Eu estive utilizando a `COde::Blocks` e gostei muito, mas com o `Mingw`, com o `VS 2010` eu consegui compilar em `Release` mas não consegui debugar, porque o debugger não mostra onde exatamente aconteceu a falha de segmentação, ele nem marca a linha no código.

Eu sempre utilizei o `Mingw`, não sei como configurar o `Code::Blocks` para debuggar com o `VS 2010 Express`, se for possível.

[image: Exemplo]
[image: Configurações]

Comment: Vai em `Settings -> Compiler and Debuger...` e edite seu poste contendo o que se encontra na tab `Toolchain Executables`

Comment: Acabei de adicionar...

Comment: Precisa de mudar o debugger para o `cdb` porque o `GDB` só funciona para o `GCC`. Se não o tiver instalado pode [pegá-lo aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Kyllopardiun, obrigado era isso mesmo :D.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Considere adicionar uma resposta

Comment: Um sugestão não relacionada diretamente a pergunta e sim com seus comentários na pergunta é trocar, caso seja possível, de IDE para o Visual Studio 2013 Express. Nele o highlight e o intellisense são muito melhores, alem de oferecer muitas outras funções, correções de bug e algumas das funcionalidades do padrão mais recente do C++. (C++11)

Comment: @TiagoGomes, infelizmente não posso fazer isso agora. Minha maquina atual é um pouco antiga, os drivers gráficos dela, não são suportados no `Windows 7`, já que o `Visual Studio 2013` só é suportado pelo `Windows 7` ou superior (segundo o site da Microsoft). Mas assim que possível pretendo fazer um upgrade. Aproveitando o comentário, será que existe uma diferença de desempenho no programa final entre o `Mingw` e `VSXXX`?.

Comment: @WalbertiEvaristo, não verá nenhuma mudança realmente significativa quanto a velocidade. Quem disser o contrário provavelmente fará apenas alguns testes com veracidade comprometida e qualidade questionável. **Se o seu código for eficiente não há por quê se preocupar com isso.**

Comment: Eu decidi utilizar o `Visual Studio` por conta de que a `PhysX` só é suportada nele (até tentei compilar com o `Mingw`, mas sem sucesso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O GNU Debugger não é compatível com o compilador da Microsoft e apesar de parecer estranho a Microsoft fornece o CDB debugger como um *item "opcional"* e por tanto deve ser feito o download a partir do site deles:

[CDB Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

<sub>*Me parece que fornecem um carro com o volante como item opcional.*</sub>

E configurar o path no Code::Blocks em  `Settings -> Compiler and Debuger ->Toolchain Executables`

Uma outra opção, embora não seja tão relevante a pergunta seria usar o [Visual Studio 2013 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787) que realmente melhorou muito em relação ao 2010.